# Configuring folder to use SSL

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I have a domain: http://example.xoc.uam.mx. I want to require the use of SSL in it (it's a folder of a server). I have this code in the .htaccess but it's not working. What I am doing wrong?

```
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^example\.xoc\.uam\.mx$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.xoc.uam.mx$1 [R,L]
```

PS. I already have all the SSL features working, this is, I think, the only thing I miss.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some errors.  To parse domain name you must use `HTTP_HOST` instead of `REQUEST_URI`.

You can replace it by this one

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.xoc\.uam\.mx$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.222\.333\.444$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working fine, however, when I get to the site by Ip.Ad.dr.ess/ExampleFolder it won't activate the SSL. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can see my edited code. Don't forget to replace it by your real server ip address. If you have this domain only, you can remove last two *RewriteCond*

Comment: Thanks. I have one more thing to do, but now I have a good way to go.